# Error on packages installation in Julia language

Tags: julia

I cannot install new packages with error:

```
curl_multi_socket_action: 8  
@ Downloads.Curl /home/abuild/rpmbuild/BUILD/julia-1.6.3/usr/share/julia/stdlib/v1.6/Downloads/src/Curl/utils.jl:36
```

How can I fix this problem?

Julia Version: 1.6.3
OS: openSUSE TW

Comment: Maybe add some info about what you did to get this error and what package you want to add?

Comment: i have the same problem with 1.6, but 1.7 downloaded from https://julialang.org/downloads/ works